# How to pass arguments from Controller to a Model method in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, models, controllers

I am including a custom method for formatting my json data.

My controller looks like this:

```
("def" is taken out for brevity sake)

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @user, :methods => [:follower_count(params[:id])] }
end
```

My model looks like this:

```
 def follower_count user_id
    User.find(user_id).friendships.count
  end
```

However, this throws a syntax error, unexpected '('.

I'm not sure how to pass in an argument to the follower_count method in the controller. I tried wrapping in square – didn't work. I tried no brackets – still doesn't work. How do you pass in arguments?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax error tells you that you're trying to use symbol `:follower_count` as a function.  But the main question is why are you passing `user_id` to instance method when you already have it available as `@id` in all instance methods of `User` class.

Correct code looks something like this:

```
# controller
format.json { render json: @user, :methods => [:follower_count] }

# User.rb
def follower_count
    friendships.count
end
```

Comment: Wow. Touche – That is much easier! I guess I didn't realize the method in the model was already scoped for the current user. Thanks.

Comment: but what if i want to pass an argument along with the method name? I want to pass request object since this object can not be accessed through model.